# C# Autenticación con smart card en client-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, smartcard, ssl

Estoy trabajando en un sitio web con arquitectura cliente-servidor el cual necesita autenticación mediante una smart card.

El flujo es el siguiente:

1. El usuario ingresa su smart card, que contiene un certificado, en el hardware correspondiente y es detectado por el navegador.
2. El usuario ingresa al sitio web y tiene la opción de autenticarse con su certificado.
3. El servidor valida que el certificado sea correcto y lo autentica.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no encuentro la forma de poder acceder al certificado de la smart card desde el servidor. Las diferentes soluciones que encontré son todas para obtener certificados del servidor y no desde el cliente.

¿Es posible enviar el certificado en un request al servidor?

**Update 1**:
Mediante esta guía https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/315588/how-to-secure-an-asp.net-application-using-client-side-certificates pude crear un ejemplo y configurar el IIS para que requiera SSL con certificado.

Creé una regla many-to-one de tipo Issuer con SubField O y CN la autoridad certificadora que quiero aceptar, y me da el siguiente error.

Error HTTP 403.7 - Forbidden

La página a la que está intentando obtener acceso requiere que el explorador tenga un certificado de cliente de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL) que reconozca el servidor web.

Comment: Hola, creo que tienes que configurar IIS para que acepte la autenticación por certificados, en [este](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/315588/how-to-secure-an-asp.net-application-using-client-side-certificates) artículo hablan de ello y en [este](https://blogs.iis.net/rlucero/iis-7-walkthrough-one-to-one-client-certificate-mapping-configuration) otro. Estaré atento a las respuestas porque es algo que me interesa aunque nunca he llegado a implementarlo

Comment: Hola, no se si me expliqué bien. En esos links se instalan en el IIS certificados que fueron solicitados al cliente. En mi caso, el certificado ya lo tiene, y lo que quiero hacer es comprobar que es valido. En vez de que ingrese usuario y contraseña, muestra el certificado que lo identifica

Comment: Hola de nuevo, igual los enlaces que te he pasado no eran los mas adecuados, igual [esta](https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/11/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-1-introduction/) serie de post se sirven. Yo conozco el funcionamiento más o menos, aunque no para poder darte una respuesta rápida

Answer (score 1):

Si has configurado IIS correctamente con el mapping requiriendo certificado de cliente con Many-to-1, desde tu página en .NET debes poder acceder al certificado de cliente:

```
X509Store almacen = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
try
{
    almacen.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); // en modo solo lectura
    X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = almacen.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2Collection buscando = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "buscando", true);
    X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
    if (buscando.Count > 0)
    {
       clientCertificate = findResult[0];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Ups, no hay certificado con esas características.");
    }
    return clientCertificate;
}
catch (Excepcion ex)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    almacen.Close();
}
```

en el web.config de tu aplicación, asegúrate de tener configurada la sección de los certificados:

```
<security>
    <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
</security>
```

o bien la opción "SslRequireCert" si esta opción esta bloqueada en el machine.config deberás permitirla o en la sección de configuración de Certificado SSL de tu IIS aceptar los certificados de clientes.